# The problem having different vms with the same sql server Licence key

Tags: sql-server, license

I was hired in a new company 1 year ago. After doing all important stuff, i'm now hunting for problems and etc.

Using a powershell that can give me the licence key using to install the SQL Server, I could find that we have 5 different vms, using the same SQL Server 2012 with the same licence key.

probably the old people here just used the same EXE and the same KEY to install all sql servers in all vms created because they didn't know about it ( just clicking next next next next)

is there a way to fix this and is it possible to edit to elicence key to use a valid one ( a diferent one for each instance on each vm?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a "License Key" it's an "Activation Key", which simply controls the Edition of SQL Server that is running.  Its only relationship to licensing is that it may help you determine what licenses need to be assigned to the server.

Licenses are assigned to servers using external bookkeeping, like in a Software Asset Management Solution or an Excel Spreadsheet.

For instance, SQL Server on Docker Containers and the Visual Studio Subscription Downloads all come with the key already embedded in the installer.  Both of these can be used for production deployments by simply assigning the appropriate licenses to the servers without changing the key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer david. Maybe I'm confusing. The patch that I'm using inside the Powershell is `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\setup\"DigitalProductId"`. Nwo I'm confused even more because this is the "key" we use while instaling the sql server. can this key be the same on every server? it's just a key to say" this is really a sql server 2012"?? and before you answer, I'm right now reading and studying about this because i tought ( for 6 years ) that this key is the one we "buy" for each SQL.

Comment: SQL Server is licensed per core, with multiple core licenses required for each server. So there's just no way a single key can be tied to the licensing footprint required for a server.